# do calculation on numbers in text using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, eval

I have an html file with multiple paragraphs, each one has a top and left tag that is in `px`. I'm trying to translate this numbers to percent using regex. my page width and height is `500px` and `1000px` respectivly. For example for this text:

```
<p "position:absolute;left:200px;top:200px"></p>
```

I want the result to be:

```
<p "position:absolute;left:40%;top:20%"></p>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: thanks. but I'm looking for regex approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture patterns via regex but cannot have computation done through them.

In your case you could use a regex like

```
<p.*left:(\d{1,3})px;top:(\d{1,3}).*p>
```

This regex will spit out 2 matches which would the captured numbers. You can now convert them and replace using the captured group number.

Or you could simply use a callback to replace method

```js
str = '<p "position:absolute;left:200px;top:200px"></p>';
pattern = /\d+/g;
function replacer(match) {
 match = (match/500)*100 + '%';
  return match;
}
str = str.replace(pattern, replacer);
str = str.replace(/px/g, '');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. using this code I can capture the top and left number as $1 and $2. how can I do calculation on them. I tried eval() but it's not working

Comment: Have a look at the edited part. You can build on this.